# Why node shebang works for Angular CLI but doesn't for my file?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, shebang

Internet is telling me Windows doesn't support shebang lines but apparently Angular Cuses it and it works. Example of file that uses it and works on Windows:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/%40angular/cli/bin/ng

If I open CMD, navigate to directory with that file and run simply `ng`, Windows will recognise that it should be run with node and executes (I presume) `node ng`. But if I try that with my own file, it doesn't work. Example of such file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';

console.log("logging test");
```

If I save that file as `test` and run it, I get `'test' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` Why is that so?

Output of `where ng`:

```
C:\Users\Dread\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng
C:\Users\Dread\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.cmd
```

Comment: What is the output of `where ng` ?

Comment: Updated question and now I understand. ng.cmd is in my path and when I run `ng`, cmd runs this file. I checked file and see it simply runs accompanying ng file. If I uninstall globally installed `ng` and repeat steps in question, it stops working. Am I correct in my assumption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your output of `where ng` it is clear what is happening.

Windows does not support shebang lines, so what you have read is correct. What Windows does support is file extensions and you do have an executable extension available.

You *do* have `ng` but it is not being run directly. `ng.cmd` is almost certainly a batch file that runs `node ng`.

When you run `ng` Windows searched your path for all possible executable file formats (`exe`, `bat`, `cmd`, etc) and ran the first one that matched: `ng.cmd`.

If you want to run your script then you will have to either run it as an argument to `node`, i.e. `node test`, or create a `test.cmd` file that does the same.

Comment: Windows (well, cmd.exe) also supports marking various extensions as executable (%PATHEXT%) – by default even .js is in there, though it's already claimed by wscript...

Comment: It does, but for un-extensioned files like the one in the question you have to use a helper "executable" of some description.